# How to get rid of Japanese language on WPS document templates?

Tags: japanese

How do you get rid of Japanese language on "WPS Office" document templates?

[templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ObCZ.png)

Comment: Attached Image /\

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, They are Traditional Chinese used in HongKong and Taiwan. WPS Office is a Chinese product by [KingSoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsoft). I prefer to use LibreOffice, the default package of Ubuntu.